# Wrong html-tags

Tags: python, html

is there a simple way to correct wrongly interpreted html-tags? 
For example: I have the following text in a html-file:

```
<div class=paragraph style=" padding:0.00pt 18.48pt 0.00pt 19.68pt; text-align:left;"><span class=font29 style=" line-height:10.56pt;">Here is some text. and here comes a <wrongly interpreted html-tag> how can the "<" and ">" be removed?</span></div>
```

How can I extract and correct all the wrongly interpreted html tags?
I thought of a list where I add all "correct" html-tags. But I'm not sure if this will work...

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Don't make invalid markup in the first place. Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>` in your text. Once you break an egg, it's hard to stuff it back into the shell.

Comment: Hm, the thing is that all my files contain already "<" and ">"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). For instance `<` should be written in HTML as `&lt;` (less than) and `>` as `&gt;` (greater than).

Your string would then look like:

```
<div><span>Here is some text. and here comes a &lt;wrongly interpreted html-tag&gt; how can the "&lt;" and "&gt;" be removed?</span></div>
```

Comment: But the problem is that my files already contain these wrong html-tags - it's the fault of the Abbey Fine Reader :(

Comment: In that case, lodge a bug report with Abbyy, and find another conversion tool in the mean time. There is no shortage of results on Google for "PDF to HTML".

Comment: Hm, and what about this: I search for all occurrences of "<" which are not followed by "class" or "/" [here, a list would be great for all cases which are valid tags]. All the "<" in the found examples should be removed. 
I think this should work...so, my (final?) question is: How would a possible implementation of this idea look like?

Comment: I could write some lines like: "[x for x in my_list if not x.startswith('< class')]" and so on. But is there any better implementation?